# Ordenar posiciones de datos de un array

Tags: php, array

Estoy leyendo una Api que me trae los horóscopos y de vez en cuando algún horóscopo falta.

Haciendo lo siguiente guardo solo los horóscopos que me llegan en un array:

```
    $datosJson = [];

    foreach ($datos_diario['horoscopo'] as $key => $value) {
      array_push($datosJson, $key);
    }

    var_dump($datosJson);
```

Lo que me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "acuario"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "aries"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "cancer"
  [3]=>
  string(11) "capricornio"
  [4]=>
  string(9) "escorpion"
  [5]=>
  string(7) "geminis"
  [6]=>
  string(3) "leo"
  [7]=>
  string(5) "libra"
  [8]=>
  string(6) "piscis"
}
```

El problema que tengo es, que al recorrer con un for esa información, Acuario está en la posición 0, por lo que el horóscopo no se me muestra ordenado.

Creando otro array donde está la información completa, cómo puedo decirle a $datosJson: mira, la posición 0 tiene que ser Aries, como está en $horoscopo y que se ordenen, no importa si desde la api me llegan 2, 3, 11, 12 horóscopos.

```
$horoscopos = ['aries', 'tauro', 'geminis', 'cancer', 'leo', 'virgo', 
'libra', 'escorpion', 'sagitario', 'capricornio', 'acuario', 'piscis'];
```

Probe lo siguiente:
Realizar un foreach sobre horoscopo y con la siguiente logica:
El value que trae horoscopo existe en datosJson? Si existe no hago nada, si no lo elimino de horoscopo y de esa forma horoscopo me queda con los datos que me llegan y ordenados, el problema es que al hacer el unset se eliminan las posiciones y si no me llega Tauro por ejemplo, Aries me queda en la posicion 0 y geminis en la 2 y al hacer el for da error porque no encuentra la 1:

```
    foreach ($horoscopos as $key => $value) {
      $indice = array_search($value ,$datosJson,false);
      if ($indice == ""){
        unset($horoscopos[$key]);
      }
    }
```

Devuelve:

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "aries"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "geminis"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "cancer"
  [4]=>
  string(3) "leo"
  [6]=>
  string(5) "libra"
  [7]=>
  string(9) "escorpion"
  [9]=>
  string(11) "capricornio"
  [11]=>
  string(6) "piscis"
}
```

En base a lo ultimo, se pueden ordenar las posiciones de forma ascendente cambiando los valores que tiene para que me quede asi? Eso solucionaria todo.

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "aries"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "geminis"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "cancer"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "leo"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "libra"
  [5]=>
  string(9) "escorpion"
  [6]=>
  string(11) "capricornio"
  [7]=>
  string(6) "piscis"
}
```

**SOLUCIONADO GRACIAS A LA RESPUESTA DE PHPMyguel**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que eso depende de la implementación. Al ajustarlo al calendario, creo que Piscis o Acuario salen en primer lugar. Creo que el horóscopo tradicional no tiene muchas chances de cambiar, así que bien podrías tener tú la lista creada en memoria

Comment: @Alfabravo ahi agregue otra cosa que hice al final

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Siempre recomiendo que antes de meterse en un problema que tendría sentido que tuviese alguna solución, se mire la documentación del lenguaje en cuestión, ya que la mayoría de las veces ya tiene una función que nos resuelve el problema.

Lo que tú tienes es un grupo **A**, que no es otra cosa que un `array` con toda la información y que además se encuentra ordenado apropiadamente:

```
$horoscopos = ['aries', 'tauro', 'geminis', 'cancer', 'leo', 'virgo', 
'libra', 'escorpion', 'sagitario', 'capricornio', 'acuario', 'piscis'];
```

Luego, por otro lado tienes el grupo **B** que es otro `array` que además de poder llegarte con valores que faltan, también va a llegarte desordenado.

```
$horoscopos2 = ['tauro', 'aries', 'leo'];
```

Si te he entendido bien, hasta ahí correcto.

Lo que necesitas es conseguir los valores coincidentes en **A** y en **B** ordenados según el orden que aporta **A**. Para ello existe una función llamada `array_intersect()` que nos devuelve justo lo que deseamos.

De esta manera podríamos solucionarlo con:

```
var_dump(array_intersect($horoscopos,$horoscopos2));
```

Esto obtendría:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "aries" [1]=> string(5) "tauro" [4]=> string(3) "leo" }
```

Que según creo es justo lo que necesitas.

**Referencia:** [array_intersect()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-intersect.php)

**EDIT**

A través de la función `array_values()` puedes borrar los índices (realmente lo que hace es obtener solo los valores, dejando los índices fuera) para que te genere unos nuevos basados en la posición que ocupa cada elemento dentro del `array`.

```
$horoscopos = ['aries', 'tauro', 'geminis', 'cancer', 'leo', 'virgo', 
'libra', 'escorpion', 'sagitario', 'capricornio', 'acuario', 'piscis'];

$horoscopos2 = ['tauro', 'aries', 'leo'];


$array_final = array_intersect($horoscopos3,$horoscopos2);

var_dump(array_values($array_final));
```

Esto obtendría:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "aries" [1]=> string(5) "tauro" [2]=> string(3) "leo" }
```

Comment: Probe el codigo pero al parecer sigo con el mismo error que comentaba al sacar Tauro, Aries queda en la pocision 0 y Gemenis en la posicion 2 cuando tendria que estar en la 1, no preste atencion a lo que pones que obtendria, ahi esta el mismo detalle, leo esta en la posicion 4 cuando tendria que ser la 2 -> Aries 0, Tauro 1, Leo 2

Comment: Aries queda en [0] porque el array que le pasas a la función como primer parámetro debe de ser el array que contiene todos los elementos de la lista con su orden correcto. Si necesitas que esté ordenado de otra manera pásale un array con todos los signos zodiacales ordenados correctamente. El array que nos expones como el que tiene que tener los datos correctos empieza con Aries en la posición [0]

Comment: Si la api me devuelve Piscis, Aries, en base al array donde esta la lista completa seria que Aries es la posicion 0 y Piscis la 11 pero al ordenarlos en el nuevo array ahi voy a tener solo 2 por lo que Aries tiene que ir en la 0 y piscis en al 1, me explico?

Comment: Los índices en un array, son posicionales, por lo que al borrar elementos este se actualiza de tal manera que jamás va a dejar huecos vacíos entre ellos. Que parece que es lo que necesitas. Para hacer lo que quieres tendrías que tener un array asociativo: **array(
    clave  => valor,
    clave2 => valor2,
    clave3 => valor3,
    ...
    )** De esta manera si que podrías asociar un número a cada horóscopo de tal manera que al usar la función que cité en mi respuesta sigan manteniéndose esos índices que parece que necesitas.

Comment: Añadida edición para solucionar el problema que comentas.

Comment: Editada de nuevo. Tras leer muy detenidamente tus ediciones, creo que he entendido lo que quieres hacer. Que el nuevo array resultante de ejecutar la función **array_intersect** no almacene los índices y te genere unos nuevos.

Comment: Ahora si! Todo perfecto, ya al tener los indices acomodados puedo hacer el for y rellenar todo, muchisimas gracias!